# Gnome Fallback/Classic - Just a bottom panel

Tags: gnome-classic

I'm moving from openSUSE to Ubuntu and I decided to install 12.04, but I don't like Unity so I'm going to install gnome fallback, but I'd like to have only a bottom panel, as in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the top panel by Secret key combination with the panels in Oneiric is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+Right-Click

And than you can edit the bottom panel to add icons and other things using the same key combination

[image: example of adding how to add to the panel]

The <kbd>Super</kbd> key is also known as the Win or Windows key.

If you are using Precise (12.04) then for me the same key combination is required.

However, the simpler <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-Click is also useful:

**Setting up the Bottom Panel as in your image**

1. Add to the panel using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-Click bottom-panel
2. Select Gnome menu bar from the window that appears.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-Click and than Click <kbd>Move</kbd> and drag the menu to the extreme left
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right-Click the upper panel and drag all the things like wifi icon battery icon message cloud etc to the bottom-panel
5. Now lock the panel

Comment: Will the open Windows appear at the bottom?

Comment: yes you can the the ubuntu menu icon at bottom as well by same key combination and add options to the bottom panel and select gnome-menu

Comment: Pleasure, and thats a good idea to play with gnome-classic panels in VM

Comment: Very hard to get the bottom panel as the one on the picture, not as many items to add. Tried on the LiveCD, thinking twice after doing this.

Comment: Its just the setting nothing more click the icons and object which you want to move and drag them where you want